# Is it possible that the diameter of a graph be shorter than the longest shortest path?

Tags: graphs, shortest-path

I used networkx to find the diameter of a graph that I have. It gave a diameter of 4. However, I found that between two particular nodes, using networkx's shortest path function, the path length is 5. I also coded dijkstra's algorithm and BFS from scratch and both returned a shortest path length of 5 too.

Is anything wrong with this? Isn't the diameter of a graph the longest shortest path?

This is what I'm using: http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/data/Erdos/Erdos02.net

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing the number of vertices in the shortest path with the length of the path? If the shortest path contains 5 vertices, then the path length (and distance) between those vertices is 4

Comment: Ah, that was so dumb of me, I didn't even think about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diameter of a graph is, by definition, the length of the longest shortest path, i.e.,

$$\mathrm{diam}(G) = \max_{x,y\in V(G)} \min\, \{\mathrm{len}(P)\mid P\text{ is a path from }x\text{ to }y\}\,.$$

But remember that the length of a path is the number of edges it contains, not the number of vertices. (That is, a single edge is a path of length 1, not 2.)